# Google Maps: Doesn't displays on localhost

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to integrate Google Maps in my app. I've read API v3 docs, generated API key, but map loads approximately 1 time per hour. Other time zone fore map is empty

This code I use for map render in my HTML header:

```
<script src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=HERE-IS-MY-UNIQUE-KEY"></script>
<script>
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5073509,-0.1277583);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

And here is a code snippet of HTML:

```
...
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div id="map-canvas" style="height:200px;width:400px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
...
```

What can be wrong here? Why map doesn't render on regular basics?

Comment: It's hard to say just by looking, but does it work when you take the Geocoder parts out? Are you getting any error messages or anything? It would be good if you can provide as much information as possible about your issue... "help me fix my code" questions aren't generally treated too kindly around here.

Comment: What happens when you remove the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `js?=API_KEY` part to `js?v=3.exp`
This should fix your problem.

Edit 26-06-2016: Keyless access is no longer available. Thanks VikVik for the update.

Comment: This doesn't work. Effective 2016/06/22 the key is mandatory.
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html